# placing text field values seperated by comma in table using ng repeat (angular js)

Tags: javascript, html, .net, angularjs, model-view-controller

i have a multi date picker in a MVC page after picking multiple dates it will show the result in text box , i want take the text box result and place it in a table  by sorting the result using commas
for example i have 10/01/2015, 10/04/2015, 10/08/2015, 10/12/2015, 10/14/2015 dates
and my result should display in a table as shown below
[image]

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td>10/01/2015</td>
 <td>10/04/2015</td>
  .....
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `ng-repeat` needs `array` to iterate.Is `dates` array ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your dates model is `dates` and stores an array of picked dates:

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td ng-repeat="date in dates">{{ date }}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @hsz  . . i am newbie to angular ,  i dont know how to store the picked dates in array can you suugest me how to do

Comment: http://pastie.org/10485555                                                                                                             the above code is working fine but its not taking repetitive values